# Retrieve and Stores multiple data to database

Tags: php

i am currently working on a project that involves me creating a worksheet for storing student test scores and grades.

i wrote a script that retrieves users information and presents it in form of a worksheet. If changes are made to this document it saved the program stores or updates the database.

I need reviews and optimization since i am certain my coding habits are crude and needs some polishing thanks

```
<?php
//getRecord.php Script
session_start();

$_SESSION['data']['tid'] = $term = $_POST['term'];
$_SESSION['data']['sid'] = $subject = $_POST['subject'];
$_SESSION['data']['sess'] = $session = $_POST['session'];
$_SESSION['data']['class'] = $class = $_POST['class'];

#get assessment records for that class and session
$q = sprintf("SELECT grades.grade_id, concat(fname,' ', lname) 
     as name, test1, test2, test3, exam 
     FROM grades, pupils 
     WHERE pupils.pupil_id = grades.pupil_id 
     AND class_id = %d 
     AND session = '%s'
     AND term_id = %d
     AND subject_id = %d", $class, $session, $term, $subject);
     $r = $dbc->query($q);
?>  
<form method="POST" action="" >
    <table class="worksheet">
    <tr>
        <th width="2%" class="heading"></th>
        <th width="38%">Student Full Name</th>
        <th width="15%">Test 1 score</th>
        <th width="15%">Test 2 score</th>
        <th width="15%">Test 3 score</th>
        <th width="15%">Exam score</th>
    </tr>
<?php
    if ($r->num_rows > 0){  
        $i = 1;
    #if it does exist
    #get the student info for that paarticular subject
    while (list($gradeID, $stdName, $t1, $t2, $t3, $e) =     $r->fetch_array())
    {
    ?>      
    <tr>
    <td class="heading"><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $stdName; ?></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="test1[<?php echo $gradeID; ?>]" value="<?php if(isset($t1)){ echo $t1; }else{ echo 0; } ?>"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="test2[<?php echo $gradeID; ?>]" value="<?php if(isset($t2)){ echo $t2; }else{ echo 0; } ?>" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="test3[<?php echo $gradeID; ?>]" value="<?php if(isset($t3)){ echo $t3; }else{ echo 0; } ?>" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="exam[<?php echo $gradeID; ?>]" value="<?php if(isset($e)){ echo $e; }else{ echo 0; } ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="6"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" /></td></tr>
    <?php
        }   
    }else{

    //get assessment records for that class and session
    $q = sprintf("SELECT students.pupil_id, concat(fname,' ', lname) as name FROM students, pupils WHERE pupils.pupil_id= students.pupil_id 
        AND class_id = %d 
        AND session = '%s'", $class ,$session);

        $r = $dbc->query($q);
        if ($r->num_rows >= 1 ) {
        $i=1;
        //if it does exist
        //get the student info for that paarticular subject
        while (list($stdID, $stdName) = $r->fetch_array()){
        ?>      
        <tr>
        <td class="heading"><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $stdName; ?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="test1[<?php echo $stdID; ?>]" value="0"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="test2[<?php echo $stdID; ?>]" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="test3[<?php echo $stdID; ?>]" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="exam[<?php echo $stdID; ?>]" value="0" /></td>
        </tr>

        <?php
        }
        echo '
            <tr>
           <td colspan="6"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="addnew" /></td>
           </tr>';
        }
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Record" name="btnSubmit" class="btn-center"/>
    </form>
```

The setRecord Script

```
<?php
require ('../includes/connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['btnGet'])){
    require('sub-modules/getRecord.php');
}

if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])){

//i am using sample data for now but normally 
//the data are received from session
$term = $_SESSION['data']['tid'];
$subject = $_SESSION['data']['sid'];
$session = $_SESSION['data']['sess'];
$cid = $_SESSION['data']['class'];

$test1 = $_POST['test1'];
$test2 = $_POST['test2'];
$test3 = $_POST['test3'];
$exam = $_POST['exam'];

$query = '';

$insert_data = array();
$success = $failure = 0; 
$total_insertions = 0;

foreach ($test1 as $k => $v)
{
    $Test1 = $test1[$k]; $Test2= $test2[$k]; $Test3=$test3[$k]; $Exam = $exam[$k];

    if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'addnew')
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO `grades`(`pupil_id`,`subject_id`,`class_id` ,`term_id`, `test1`, `test2`, `test3`, `exam`, `session`) VALUES ($k,$subject,$cid,$term,$Test1,$Test2,$Test3,$Exam, '$session')";
    }else{
        $query = "UPDATE `grades` SET  `test1` = $Test1, `test2` = $Test2, `test3` = $Test3, `exam` = $Exam WHERE grade_id = $k";
    }

//i did this for debugging purpose so ican be able to see if the insertions 
//were complete and also see those ids that were not inserted
    $result= $dbc->query($query) or trigger_error($dbc->error);
    if ($dbc->affected_rows > 0){
        $success += 1;
    }else{
        $failure += 1;
        $insert_data[] = $k;
    }

    $total_insertions += 1;
}

if ($success == $total_insertions){
    echo 'Insertion was complete with no errors';
}elseif ($failure == $total_insertions){
    echo 'Insertion was complete with errors';
}else{
    echo '<p>Some Insertion complete with some errors</p>';
    echo "<p>IDS:";
    foreach ($insert_data as $n){
        echo $n.', ';
    }
        echo '<br>'.$dbc->error;
}
}

if (isset($_POST['action'])){
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    if ($action == 'update'){

    }
    if ($action == 'addnew'){

    }
}

?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <div>
        <label>Class: </label>
        <select name="class" id="class">

    <option value="3">Primary 1</option>
    <option value="4">Primary 2</option>
    <option value="5">Primary 3</option>
    <option value="8">Primary 4</option>
    <option value="9">Primary 5</option>
    <option value="10">Primary 6</option>   
    </select>
 </div>
 <div>
    <label>Subject: </label>
    <select name="subject" id="subject">
    <option value="1">English Language</option>
    <option value="2">Mathematics</option>
    <option value="3">Religious Knowledge</option>
    <option value="4">Civic Education</option>  
</select>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Session: </label>
    <select name="session">
        <option value="2015/2016">2015/2016</option>
     </select>
 </div>
 <div>
     <label>Term:</label>
    <select name="term">
        <option value="1">First Term</option>
        <option value="2">Second Term</option>
        <option value="3">Third Term</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="btnGet" value="Get Record"/>
</form>
```

Database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `grades` (
`grade_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`pupil_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`subject_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`term_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`test1` int(11) NOT NULL,
`test2` int(11) NOT NULL,
`test3` int(11) NOT NULL,
`exam` int(11) NOT NULL,
`subPosition` tinyint(3) DEFAULT NULL,
`session` char(9) NOT NULL,
`finalize` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`grade_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `score_id_UNIQUE` (`grade_id`),
KEY `fk_score_terms1_idx` (`term_id`),
KEY `fk_score_subjects1_idx` (`subject_id`),
KEY `fk_grades_pupils1_idx` (`pupil_id`),
KEY `fk_grades_classes1_idx` (`class_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=47 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `grades`
--

INSERT INTO `grades` (
`grade_id`, `pupil_id`, `subject_id`, `class_id`, `term_id`, `test1`, `test2`, `test3`, `exam`, `subPosition`, `session`, `finalize`) VALUES
(27, 7, 1, 3, 1, 10, 10, 0, 70, NULL, '2015/2016', 1),
(28, 3, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, '2015/2016', 0),
(29, 8, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, '2015/2016', 0),
(30, 9, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, '2015/2016', 0),
(31, 10, 1, 3, 1, 0, 5, 0, 0, NULL, '2015/2016', 0),
(32, 7, 2, 3, 1, 5, 7, 10, 0, NULL, '2015/2016', 1),
(33, 3, 2, 3, 1, 6, 9, 10, 0, NULL, '2015/2016', 1),
(34, 8, 2, 3, 1, 5, 7, 5, 0, NULL, '2015/2016', 1),
(35, 9, 2, 3, 1, 7, 7, 7, 0, NULL, '2015/2016', 1),
(36, 10, 2, 3, 1, 9, 9, 8, 0, NULL, '2015/2016', 1),
(42, 11, 2, 4, 1, 5, 10, 0, 0, NULL, '2015/2016', 1),
(46, 11, 1, 4, 1, 4, 10, 7, 0, NULL, '2015/2016', 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full review, just a couple of things I noticed:

**Security**

All of your queries are vulnerable to SQL Injection. You should use either mysqli_ or PDO with prepared statements.

Your setRecord script is also vulnerable to reflected XSS (`echo $n.', ';` where n is user supplied).

Your code is also vulnerable to CSRF and stored XSS.

**Structure**

Your PHP file contains HTML code, CSS code, and PHP code. This is definitely too much. Personally, I would separate it as much as possible.

The first thing I would do is put the CSS info in its own file.

Then, I would introduce functions; for example `getStudentsByClass`, `getGradesByClass`, `insertGrade`, etc. This makes your code reusable, more readable, and means that you can get rid of most of your comments.

You should also introduce functions for duplicate code. For example, instead of this: `"<?php if(isset($t1)){ echo $t1; }else{ echo 0; } ?>` you might have

```
function default($value, $default) 
{
    if (isset($value) {
        return $value;
    } else {
        return $default;
    }
}
```

Then it's just `echo default($t1, 0);`.

The same way, you might want to put the building of the `input` tag into a function.

**Naming**

- names should all start with a lower-case character. You should never have variable names that only differ in case (eg `Test1` vs `test1`), as it is highly confusing.
- names should almost never be only one character. `r` might be `gradesResult`, `e` might be `exam`, and so on.

**Style**

- your indention and spacing are partly off. You can use an IDE to fix this.
- your placement of `{` is not consistent. It should go on the next line for functions and classes, and on the same line for everything else.

**Misc**

- Why do you store some values in a session? This doesn't seem to be needed.
- Same things should have the same name. English isn't my first language, but is there really a difference between pupils and students?
- all SQL keywords should be uppercase. You generally follow this rule, but didn't for `as`.
- I would get rid of variables that you only use in one or two places. `$test1` for example is only used once, and `$Test1` only twice. Their name also doesn't add any new information.
- I would declare variables as late as possible; that way a reader doesn't have to keep them in mind until they are actually necessary.

Comment: (`default` is a keyword, probably a bad idea to use that as a function name.)

Comment: @Mat Thanks, that's of course correct. `getDefault` or `defaultValue` or something might work instead.

Comment: i normally use mysqli prepared statements but i quit on it because most times i cant debug errors with it, especially errors as a result of database queries. i cant see the generated query so that i can see where i am wrong. In security i found out you kept mentioning XSS and CSRF is there any way or any materials that can help me avoid such security loops

Comment: @SylvesterHilary With mysqli/PDO, you should check the return values of execute, prepare, etc; that way, you at least find out which query fails (being open to SQL injection is def. not an alternative). You can also enable your mysql error log for debugging, or add a debug variable and echo queries when it is enabled. XSS/CSRF: owasp is always a great resource for general info: [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29). for PHP specifics, I would just google it.

Comment: @tim how can you echo queries in prepared statement i am trying to do this for an update to debug it but its just a nightmare

Comment: @SylvesterHilary with the actual values? You can't really do that in PHP (but I'm not sure why you would want to; you should be fine debugging it with `?` instead of the actual values, eg via [debugDumpParams](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php) or by just echoing the query you build). If you do need the query with the actual values, you would need to do it via the dbms, see eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786322/) for mysql (or use some other work-around, as in the example in the first link).